# postgresql partial optimization of query involving coalesce -- what is happening?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql (v9.3) query to which I sometimes know the answer. I am writing this:

```
select coalesce( <the answer>, count( distinct bar ) ) from foo;
```

Where < the answer > is null when in fact I don't know the answer.

"foo" is fairly large; this query takes 2 seconds. If I drop coalesce and simply count( distinct bar ), the resulting query takes 7 seconds. Using pgadmin "explain", these two queries have exactly the same plan.

Can someone explain what is happening? If it can "partially" optimize this query, why can't postgres completely optimize it? Is there some way to force it to check < the answer > before spending two seconds thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite this query into:

```
select coalesce( <the answer>, ( SELECT count( distinct bar ) from foo ) ) ;
```

Here if `<the answer>` is not null, the subquery in the second argument won't be evaluated at all.

Comment: Kordirko, Great... that works.... In fact, I tried to simplify my question to ask it. The concrete problem into which this fits is when I want to calculate "whichever aggregates are missing" from among four aggregates calculated. So I have `select a1( ... ), a2( ... ), ... a4( ... )' from foo`.

Can you extend your suggestion to cover this case?

Answer (score 0):

Kordiko's answer satisfies the basic question. To answer the expanded question in the comment to K's answer, it turns out the count( distinct ) aggregate is by far the slowest; the other three are go faster, and do not go very much slower when combined. So something like this seems promising (modulo some composite type):

```
select case when <distinct case is null> then
        ( select (<all aggregates>) from foo )
    when <some other is null> then
        ( select (<known value for distinct>, <aggregates besides distinct>) from foo)
    else
        ( select (<all known values>)) end;
```